# AWS Amplify Hosting with CI/CD v/s manual with S3/Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Can someone help me understand the AWS Amplify Hosting? How does it work when we connect a github repository for auto hosting?

I used to think that this would go to an S3/Cloudfront - under the hood. But, after hosting a website using Amplify Hosting, I can see that it has not generated any new Cloudfront distribution. So where is it hosted?

Does Amplify have another CDN? Is it similar to the S3/Cloudfront hosting? Or do we pay a penalty for the convenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Support responded to this question on Twitter. https://twitter.com/VSolegaonkar/status/1424037405275824131. The Amplify hosting also generates an S3/CloudFront under the hood - but it does not show up on the console.